# In a multithreaded c++ program using boost, is there any way to get a pointer to the current thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I need to know the identity of the current thread to keep track of which threads are making certain requests to a shared data structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `boost::this_thread::get_id()` to get a `boost::thread::id` representing the thread.

I don't think you can get a pointer to a `boost::thread` object, because the thread doesn't necessarily have one attached. And it cannot make one because it might have one attached.

Answer (score 0):

No way, but you can support hashmap of pairs: thread-id thread.